# How do I scan text for multiple strings?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm scanning through a product name to check if a specific string exists in it. Right now it works for a single string, but how can I can scan for multiple strings? e.g. i'd like to scan for both apple and microsoft

```
product.name.downcase.scan(/apple/)
```

If the string is detected i get ["apple"]
if not then it returns nil [ ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [regex alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
product.name.downcase.scan(/apple|microsoft/)
```

If all you need to know is whether the string contains any of the specified strings, you should better use single match [=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) instead of `scan`.

```
str = 'microsoft, apple and microsoft once again'

res = str.scan /apple|microsoft/ # => res = ["microsoft", "apple", "microsoft"]
# do smth with res

# or
if str =~ /apple|microsoft/
  # do smth
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also skip regular expressions altogether:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'orange'].any?{|s| product.name.downcase.match(s)}
```

or

```
['apple', 'pear', 'orange'].any?{|s| product.name.downcase[s]}
```